# Arch AMDGPU-PRO hw_init failed -110

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, amd-graphics

So I have arch running on a mining rig and everything was running fine until I tried adding a 5th GPU.  On boot I get an error that says hw_init of IP block failed -110.  I've switched around risers and cards and the same thing happens.

Interestingly, if I switch my new card to another PCI-E slot, it still doesn't run but the one switched over will.  It's almost as if arch is keeping track of which GPUs I've had and not running the new one.

I found this recent [thread](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103463) that displays the issue but it seems it may just be a kernel bug, in which case, do I have to just wait for a patch to the linux kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up swapping out that card for one that I knew worked.  As it turns out, the GPU is dead.